# Define partitions to install Linux but considering Security and Administration aspects/concerns

Tags: partition, system-installation, hard-disk, partition-table, hfs+

**Scenario**: for simplicity - consider that exists a hard disk of 500GB to only install Linux (for example Ubuntu, Debian or Fedora) - ***and*** if exists a hard disk of 750GB or 1TB then 500GB are dedicated for Linux (as first case) and the rest of the disk for Windows.

I read many tutorials about best practices about to define partitions to install Linux, for the most common or general scenario is suggested:

```
/boot 100MB
/swap x2 current RAM if is minor or equals of 4GB
/     50GB to 100 GB
/home 50GB to 100 GB
```

**Note**: for above is important consider the order of the partitions too.

Until here all is OK and `gparted` can be used in peace.

Now considering the **security** and **administration** aspects/concerns then is available the following:

```
#1
/boot 100MB
/swap x2 current RAM if is minor or equals of 4GB
/     50GB to 100 GB
/home 50GB
#2
/var
/usr
/tmp
```

**Question 1** Is the order of *part #2* correct? or it does not matter? In many tutorials these partitions of the part 2 appear or are only mentioned but never indicated about their order - therefore not sure if is not important or not. It can be problematic later.

**Question 2**: What are the recommended sizes for `/var`, `/usr` and `/tmp` partitions? This question would be tricky but I am assuming is there a kind of guidance or rule thumb for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 MiB for `/boot` is not enough, I recommend 1 GiB. It varies in different distributions, but on my system initramfs is 36 MiB and vmlinuz 11 MiB. So with 100 MiB you probably wouldn't be able to fit more than one bootable kernel+init on your system.
I would recommend 1 GiB, 500 MiB minimum.

Don't forget that you'll also need `/boot/efi` if you are on a UEFI system. Recommended size for `/boot/efi` [vary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313154/how-to-know-the-proper-amount-of-needed-disk-space-for-efi-partition), it's usually is between 100 or 200 MiB and 550 or 600 MiB.

If you have enough RAM you don't necessarily need swap (unless you plan using suspend to disk). Some distributions don't create swap by default and either just don't use swap or create swap on [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram).

50 GiB for `/` is good.

50 GiB for `/home` depends on what you plan to do with the system. For me (desktop with a single OS) it wouldn't be enough but for a server it's not really necessary to create a separate `/home` (but it definitely won't hurt) -- I wouldn't expect to put anything else than SSH key in my home on a server but that again might depend on the "type" of the server. If you are running server for multiple users and plan to set up something like per-user web directories with Apache (with `/home/<user>/public_html`) it makes sense to have separate `/home`. In general the size of `/home` depends on how much data will the user (users) store there.

`/tmp` shouldn't be on disk, most distribution now use [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html) and store `/tmp` in RAM.

I don't really see a use case for separate `/usr`. <strike>But if you want, you can do that.</strike> Edit: As @telcoM pointed out in the comments, having a separate `/usr` isn't a good idea and your system [may be unbootable with a separate `/usr`](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/).

Separate `/var` is useful for servers that store a lot of things in `/var`, like webservers that use `/var/html`, or for virtualization and other similar applications that use `/var` a lot. So it again depends on what you plan to do with the system.
Separate `/var` can be also useful for systems with flatpak which installs the applications to `/var/lib`. It can also prevent `/var/log` from eating all space in `/` if something goes wrong when logging (but [journald limits](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Journal#Journal_size_limit) can also prevent that).

You should also consider using something *more modern* than plain partitions. Especially if you plan to create multiple mount points. Dealing with running out of space on one of them is really painful with *fixed* partitions **but** with technologies like [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) or [btrfs (sub)volumes](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Subvolumes.html) you can make the system future proof more easily. Moving free space from filesystem to another (e.g. shrinking `/home` to make more space for `/var`) isn't trivial with partitions (because they cannot be resized to the left), but relatively easy with LVM and with btrfs this isn't an issue at all.

Comment: [Newer versions of `systemd` may actually no longer support having `/usr` as a separate mount point.](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/) Some distributions are in fact already proceeding towards the next step: [merging `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/lib` and/or `/lib64` to their `/usr/*` equivalents](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/), and replacing the root-level directories with compatibility symlinks. [Debian 12 "bookworm" will only support merged /usr](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - about `"but for server I wouldn't even create a separate /home"` pls consider to expand a little more the idea about why you would take that approach

Comment: Interesting about the 1GB for `/boot` it is for Ubuntu. I am going to do a research about that.

Comment: I have added a little bit more information about the separate `/home` to my answer. There's nothing wrong with having separate `/home`, but it's usually separate for easy backup and/or reinstallation etc. which usually doesn't play such a big role on a server where you usually don't store data in your home. But your mileage may vary and if you plan to set up a server where users will use their home directories, it's better to have it separate.

Comment: And whether to have something separate or not also depends on the storage technology you choose -- with standard partitions I would definitely recommend going for less. Partitions are not flexible and trying to shrink your `/home` to make more space for `/var` for example could be very complicated. With LVM or btrfs it's way easier so making more things separate isn't a big deal.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny about `/boot/efi if you are on a UEFI system` - what to choice if the hardware is old? - therefore raw/plain `BIOS` - and what should be the size - 1GB too?. pls consider add part in your current answer. Thank you

Comment: If you don't have UEFI system you don't need `/boot/efi`.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny but I would need `/boot` with **1gb**? it for non-uefi environment?

Answer (score 1):

The [CIS](https://www.cisecurity.org/) benchmark for Linux systems does require separate partitions for different directory trees but, unless you're under a mandate of some kind these don't always make sense. CIS does not recommend making `/usr` a separate partition and I really have not seen that since SunOS days. `/tmp` should be a tmpfs file system in most cases. Pulling out `/var` and maybe also `/var/log` as separate partitions can make your life easier in the long run. `/opt` is another possibility based on your needs.

`/home` should be separate to clearly delineate user data from the OS.

Always use LVM instead of fixed partitions. You can adjust or add storage when the need arises.

If you're concerned about security, consider implementing LUKS encryption either on whole disks or on specific data disks.

Answer (score 0):

-Consider the following! Partitioning disk only if the system was going to be installed on more than one disk, to which you could set one disk to `/home` for users files and the rest to the system itself! As it is a simple system and from what I saw on a disk that has another system installed, it would be better for you to divide the disk, the partitions for linux only for `/swap`, the `/"root"` and the `/home` users area, so if if you wanted to later install or update the system you wouldn't have much trouble installing a new disk just for `/home` so when you update the system the users files would remain available without problems on another disk and the space that the old partition `/home` would be occupying could be used to increase the `/"root"` partition size! So try to divide the disk into three basic partitions, the `/"root"`, the `/home` and the `/swap` partition.